# Change specific part of a string

Tags: powershell

I've got a .txt-File with some text in it:

```
Property;Value
PKG_GUID;"939de9ec-c9ac-4e03-8bef-7b7ab99bff74"
PKG_NAME;"WinBasics"
PKG_RELATED_TICKET;""
PKG_CUSTOMER_DNS_SERVERS;"12314.1231
PKG_CUSTOMER_SEARCH_DOMAINS;"ms.com"
PKG_JOIN_EXISTING_DOMAIN;"True"
PKG_DOMAINJOIN_DOMAIN;"ms.com"
PKG_DOMAINJOIN_USER;"mdoe"
PKG_DOMAINJOIN_PASSWD;"*******"
```

So now, is there a way to replace those *'s with e.g. numbers or sth. ?
If so, may you tell me how to do it?

Comment: Open the file in the text editors like editPlus or vi (version available for windows)... and then you can find and replace the * with whatever you want with simple replace all command...

Comment: @AtulDravid-WhitePvt.Ltd., I don't think that's what OP means; rather how to do the same using Powershell script.

Comment: @BenJ I think you are saying you want to replace the asterisks between the quotes? Can you include in the question what the desired output is. Also, SO is not a code writing service so if you can at least show something you have tried the Community can help improve it for you to suit your needs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Much like Rahul I would use RegEx as well. Considering the application I'd run Get-Content through a ForEach loop, and replace text as needed on a line-by-line basis.

```
Get-Content C:\Path\To\File.txt | ForEach{$_ -replace "(PKG_DOMAINJOIN_PASSWD;`")([^`"]+?)(`")", "`${1}12345678`$3"}
```

That would output:

```
Property;Value
PKG_GUID;"939de9ec-c9ac-4e03-8bef-7b7ab99bff74"
PKG_NAME;"WinBasics"
PKG_RELATED_TICKET;""
PKG_CUSTOMER_DNS_SERVERS;"12314.1231
PKG_CUSTOMER_SEARCH_DOMAINS;"ms.com"
PKG_JOIN_EXISTING_DOMAIN;"True"
PKG_DOMAINJOIN_DOMAIN;"ms.com"
PKG_DOMAINJOIN_USER;"mdoe"
PKG_DOMAINJOIN_PASSWD;"12345678"
```

On second thought, I don't know if I'd do that. I might import it as a CSV, update the property, and export the CSV again.

```
Import-CSV C:\Path\To\File.txt -Delimiter ";" |%{if($_.Property -eq "PKG_DOMAINJOIN_PASSWD"){$_.value = "12345678";$_}else{$_}|export-csv c:\path\to\newfile.txt -delimiter ";" -notype
```

Answer (score 0):

If You are using Powershell V2.0 (Hopefully) you can try something like below. `gc` is short hand for `get-content` commandlet.

```
(gc D:\SO_Test\test.txt) -replace '\*+','12345678'
```

With this the resultant data would be as below (notice the last line)

```
Property;Value 
PKG_GUID;"939de9ec-c9ac-4e03-8bef-7b7ab99bff74" 
<Rest of the lines here> 
PKG_DOMAINJOIN_USER;"mdoe" 
PKG_DOMAINJOIN_PASSWD;"12345678" <-- Notice here; *'s changed to numbers
```

Comment: awesome.That helps alot. To go a step further, how does this work if the *'s are written passwords like 'ad89un2' and they are different in every .txt File. So that I want to go through all this files and replace the letters between the two exclamation marks with *'s.

Comment: That can't be achieved by single line code. You will have to loop through the files list and can use regex to replace the string. Don't get me wrong but I would suggest you to open up a separate question for the same. You can post the link of new thread as comment here.

Answer (score 0):

Rahul's answer was good, I just wanted to mention that *+ will replace all instances of a single * character or more, so it would match any other place there is at least one star. If what you posted is all you would ever expect for you sample data though this would be fine.

You could alter the regex match to make it more specific if it was needed by changing it to something like

```
\*{3,0}
```

which would match 3 or more stars, or very specific would be

```
(?<=")\*{3,}(?=")
```

which would replace 3 or more stars which are surrounded by double quotes.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a function that uses regex lookahead and lookbehind zero-length assertions to replace named parameters in a string similar to your example:

```
function replace-x( $string, $name, $value ) {
   $regex = "(?<=$([regex]::Escape($name));`").*(?=`")"
   $string -replace $regex, $value
   }
```

Its reusable for different settings in your file, e.g:

```
$settings = get-content $filename
$settings = replace-x $settings PKG_DOMAINJOIN_USER foo
$settings = replace-x $settings PKG_DOMAINJOIN_PASSWD bar
```